# Which manifolds are a sphere bundle in more than one way?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Certain spheres admit nontrivial fibrations, i.e. the Hopf fibrations and the maps to projective spaces.  Also, a product of spheres is a sphere bundle in more than one way.

> Are there manifolds which are sphere bundles in more than one way, not factoring through the above examples?

Comment: A compact Lie group $G$ having two subgroups $H$ and $K$ both isomorphic to $SU(2)$ is a $3$-sphere bundle over both $G/H$ and $G/K$. I think this would count as a new class of examples.

Comment: Check out Jason de Vito's answer to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129001/fiber-bundles-with-same-total-spaces-but-different-base-spaces

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example, involving $\operatorname{SU}(4)$.  I can't produce arrows so I will write the examples as homogeneous spaces.  We have $\operatorname{SU}(4)/\operatorname{SU}(3) =S^7$ and $\operatorname{SU}(4)/\operatorname{Sp}(2)=S^5$. I should say that for me the term "sphere bundle" can mean that either the fiber or the base is a sphere, and that may not be common usage.